# Playwright's page.evaluate always return undefined

Tags: playwright, playwright-test

this is my code.
very simple, I want to know if an element is in viewport.

for some reason I can't understand I keep getting undefined.
the element exists but nothing happens

in the I see the `x` but the `q` is never seen.

```
async function isItemInViewport( page ) {
    console.log( 'x' );
    await page.evaluate( () => {
        console.log( 'q' );
        const lastMenuItem = document.querySelectorAll( '.nav-menu--dropdown.nav-menu__container .lastitem-class-for-playwright-test' )[ 0 ].getBoundingClientRect();
        console.log(lastMenuItem );
        let isInViewport = false;
        if (
            lastMenuItem.top >= 0 &&
            lastMenuItem.left >= 0 &&
            lastMenuItem.bottom <= ( window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight ) &&
            lastMenuItem.right <= ( window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth )
        ) {
            isInViewport = true;
        }
        return isInViewport;
    } );
}
```

Comment: You forgot to `return page.evaluate( () => {`. `console.log("q")` is never seen because that code runs in the browser console, not Node. It's weird to `document.querySelectorAll(...)[0]`. Might as well `document.querySelector(...)` instead.

Comment: Thanks, 
Now I get this error:


`    page.evaluate: ReferenceError: page is not defined
    > 247 |     return await page.evaluate( () => {

with a carrot under the evaluate.
`

Comment: Depends on how you're calling it. Are you passing `page` in as a parameter to `isItemInViewport`, and `page` is a valid Puppeteer page? Please show a [mcve].

Comment: Yes, I pass the page as a parameter, it is valid because I use it in other places in the same test...
What could be the issue?

Comment: Again, I'd need to see a [mcve]. If you're in fact passing in the parameter `page` as a valid Puppeteer page, then nothing in the code shown here would cause that error. So it's not reproducible, which means it's impossible to help.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I end up doing:

```
async function isItemInViewport( page, item ) {

    return await page.evaluate( ( item ) => {
        let isVisible = false;

        const element = document.querySelector( item );
        if ( element ) {
            const rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
            if ( rect.top >= 0 && rect.left >= 0 ) {
                const vw = Math.max( document.documentElement.clientWidth || 0, window.innerWidth || 0 );
                const vh = Math.max( document.documentElement.clientHeight || 0, window.innerHeight || 0 );
                if ( rect.right <= vw && rect.bottom <= vh ) {
                    isVisible = true;
                }
            }
        }
        return isVisible;
    }, item );
}
```

And this is the function call:

```
// Assertion
        const item = '.item-css-class';
        await expect( await isItemInViewport( page, item ) ).toBeTruthy();
```